# How to create a sample question

Tags: discussion, questions, tag-wiki

When dealing with questions related to SQL, a lot of back-and-forth often occurs in comments when the question does not provide enough detail.  Mostly this involves asking the OP to provide table definitions, sample data, and expected results.

It occurs to me that an example would be useful to new users to illustrate how to ask a question.  This example could be included on the SQL tag wiki and referred to as needed.

Can something like that be done?  I suppose I could "ask" such a question and answer it myself, which would let others comment or improve upon it, but since it would not really be a question, I thought I'd ask here first.

Answer (score 3):

Some sites already have [the new Quickstart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics) page available and Stack Overflow will follow soon. There should be enough information to get new users started.