# Please provide a shortcut for [about] to link to a site's "Quick Start" page similar to [faq] and [chat]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks, tour

The new [Quick Start](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics) is very nice, and I intend to use it when moderating.

Can we have a programmed link so [about] will self-expand to be a hyperlink to `http://site/about` in a similar manner to how the markdown [chat] and [faq] links work?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-deferred]? Yes, it'd be useful once it's implemented but not very useful at the moment as the page hasn't been added to every site, yet... New users will just get lists of moderators.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards It's useful for me now due to a stroke of luck and we get a lot of green people new to Stack Exchange that respond to gentle and clear guidance like this page. I understand holding on with this request if it breaks other sites, but wouldn't people just not use [about] on sites where it was less useful / not commissioned yet?

Comment: Is "about" a good name? Would anybody read an about page to figure out how to use the site?

Comment: @sth - Better than a "how to use me" page

Comment: @sth: "About" is just an alias.  When the comment is posted, the alias can be expanded to something else, like "Quick-Start Guide".  That's how `[ask]` ([ask]) and `[answer]` ([answer]) work.