# Better to edit your wrong answer to your own question? Or create a new answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-answer

I am not sure what is the correct way to do this. I posed [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278933/asp-net-requests-and-net-4-5-strange-behavior/15343669#15343669), thought I had found the answer, posted it, and marked it as the answer to my own question. After some more testing I found that my answer does answer the question to a limited degree, but I have a new, better answer.

The symptoms point to either of these answers as possibly working, but in my specific case it was the new answer.

Am I supposed to edit my old answer? Or should I post the newer answer and mark that one as the answer? What is the etiquette here?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a legitimate reason for having more than one answer for a question.

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers: I gave more than 1 answer to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/) as did others.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified with "on a non-meta site" :)

Comment: As a tangent, it would be nice that if you introduced *drastic* changes, the votes would reset. An improved question or answer should not be saddled with negative baggage, as it tends to influence responses, nor should you keep credit for a good answer that is basically no longer there. Given the way the human psyche works, and barring some system feature I am not aware of, I'd say aggressively voted content one way or the other *shouldn't* be altered. Start fresh.

Comment: More then one answer isn't a bad idea if you are posting vastly different solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you gained more knowledge about the problem, then improve your answer.

I would only post a new answer if I am going for a totally different approach and don't want to include both in one answer because **the answer would become confusing**.

To point out just a few possible reasons for some error try to stick with only one answer.

Comment: If the symptoms could point to either of my answers, but in my specific case it was this new answer, I would think that I should create the new answer and mark that one as correct, while noting that the other answer is also correct in some cases, just not mine. Is my thinking correct? (I'll add these details to my original question.)

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't add a new answer. What you need to do is edit it. In addition, you may add the heading **UPDATE 03/28/2013**, for example, on top of your post, so people know that it's a new content. I hope it's helpful.