# Can we be notified about official posts?

Tags: feature-request, tags, notifications

From time to time we see official posts from our community managers and other SE employees here on meta like

- [Closing changes to on-hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/)
- [Introducing a brand new help-center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/)
- [A new quick-start-guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/)
- [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/)
- and many more

I really don't want to miss especially those!
And since I would like to participate in the discussion I want to hear about them instantly and not just afterwards. Can we please have a way to get notified about these?

I propose to tag such question with a new meta tag like [official](/questions/tagged/official) or some sort that I could watch. Or add all future official questions to the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.

Comment: You mean the [meta-tag:featured] tag?

Comment: Of some sort, but I contains only 2 questions.

Comment: Well it gets removed from announcements after a while. I do believe that if someone doesn't remove it, it gets automatically removed after some time. But nonetheless, it's still something you can follow for those very important announcements.

Comment: The last question in my list is not there and was asked yesterday.

Comment: It's obviously not that important to them that they want it to be featured then, and I don't really see the need for another tag that basically serves as an intermediate between not-featured and featured.

Comment: A lot of those show up in the MetaSO newsletter (that's how I hear about many of them, anyway). Agree it would be nice to have a more definite way to find these posts though.

Comment: And since I like to participate in the discussion I would like to hear about them instantly and not just afterwards.

Comment: I think [tag:official] is better than [tag:featured] as the distinction is clear. Normal user featured discussions may not always have a time frame. Official posts will generally have one.

Comment: Posts cease to be featured, but would be official forever after. It would make it easier to search for official post about something, too. +1 from me, even if for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think we need new feature, one can simply subscribe to the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag:

> [image]

This will send daily email to the address in your profile by default and you can change that via the "subscriptions" tab in your network profile, where you can edit the email address and choose the frequency: 15 minutes, 3 hours or daily.

Email after 15 minutes  is pretty much the same as live notification.

Comment: But not all "official" questions are tagged [featured].

Comment: I think most are, for couple of days at least. We can ask the team to always use this tag. :)

Comment: That would be perfect.