# Jump to latest activity from activity tab

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, highlighting

Questions having activity are pushed in the *Active questions queue* - the activity tab. Some questions contain many comments and/or answers ([Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics7)). And it is difficult to see what caused the activity.

If I click on a question in the activity tab - could the comment or answer that caused the activity please be highlighted?

Like it does when I click on a notification in the notification tab (like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186710/172011))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me correct a mistake:

> could the comment or answer that caused the activity

Comment does not cause any change in activity.

Now back to the feature, such thing is already in place, though somewhat hidden:

> [image]

For example clicking the timestamp of the [middle question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163254/152859) in the screenshot above will take the user [directly to your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics/186710#186710).

Comment: true. But comments don't qualify - they don't change the timestamp and aren't linked to from there. If you were notified about the comment there's a link from the notification.

Comment: @Kate the request is based on wrong assumption, see my edit.

Comment: Also, if someone posted an answer that was deleted, and you can't see deleted answers, you may confusingly find yourself at the top of the question not sure what the activity was.

Comment: @Kate true, but what you suggest? This feature request doesn't mention such cases.

Comment: Just explaining the edge cases. Sometimes you see a question has been active but it is not possible to go to the latest activity because it is gone now.