# Preventing asking unusual questions on Meta?

Tags: feature-request, support, meta, meta-faq

I have seen three programming questions today so far. I am sure these will be deleted soon. I have sometimes commented on these with *Wrong site man, please do read the FAQ*.

So, *My first question:* Why some experienced users downvote such questions?

Next, I assume they are really new on Meta so I ask you: *please don't be afraid of them.* 
As described in the [**Quick Start Guide For New Users**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics), we should really try to guide newcomers. Do you remember the [Informed Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed)? This may force new users to learn about the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) or to take the [Tour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tour).

So I would like to request a new feature for asking questions on Meta. All Meta users must be given the FAQ to read first. That way we can assume a person who asked a question or answered a question has read the FAQ (roughly or in detail) and he/she will know about some of the rules of Meta. I often see some comments like *...read detail on FAQ*.

Please let me quote some text from [Meta's About Page:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tour)

> **Why do we need this site?**
>   *The FAQ on all sites explicitly disallows meta-discussion, to reduce clutter and noise.*

I agree with that, but I think a FAQ section is also needed for this site instead of all the  [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) questions. For instance, as a new user, will not know this post and he/she will ask off-topic questions (such as questions about programming). This is my second feature request for adding a FAQ as a separate page.

Another quote:

> ... try to refrain from asking questions about this website itself unless you absolutely, positively have to. People don’t come here to learn about the intricacies of this website; they come here to get answers to their questions. Let’s try to help them out by not cluttering up the system with navelgazing meta-discussion.

I don't understand "*cluttering up the system with navelgazing meta-discussion*". Can this be changed to

> as decreasing of questions per a day that means rich and completeness of meta site

I sometimes think Meta activity can lead to create questions about itself (the Winter Bash Event, for example). We ask about those events and answer questions (about getting hats for fun, for example). In my opinion that will cause Meta to get too cluttered. Instead of this you should provide a clear guide, announced on some page, to reduce these questions.

**For instance**: *Winter Bash will start on ..., detail is....* before you start such an event and provide service in chat with some moderators or some experienced users about this event.

Comment: People asking questions **on any Stack Exchange site** are presented with a How to Ask FAQ and a checklist **already**. Some people just don't read, *more features are not going to change that*.

Comment: And I downvote such questions for the same reason most people downvote bad questions: they show no research effort. The user ignored all the guidance given, and post in the wrong place *in spite of all the documentation*.

Comment: I *dare* say **your** *question* is *even **more unusual*** than *all the* **programming** questions that *have ever* **been** asked *on* ***Meta***. *We* are ***all*** used **to** *seeing programming questions* on **Meta** but *rarely* **do** we see *questions* with such **gratuitous *abuse of** formatting* and **tags**.

Comment: I have done my best with editing your grammar, formatting and spelling, but I had a pretty hard time understanding what you meant with all this. You also have multiple unrelated feature requests in one post, making this too broad. Can you a) verify that the post still says what you wanted to say and b) split out the post into *separate questions*?

Comment: I suspect, however, that your grasp of English falls *just short* of the proficiency levels required to have a meaningful discussion. I could not parse your *as decreasing of questions per a day that means rich and completeness of meta site* sentence to the extent that I could massage it into proper English prose, for example. I *think* I know what you wanted to say, but it I am not confident enough to take a stab at writing a better version.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Or as Too Broad, take your pick. I **think** I understand what the OP is asking, in which case there are too many questions here, and show a lack of research about what is already there.

Comment: @Cataclysm: as for the Winter Bash event: the event was announced on the blog, and there is a separate Winter Bash site. But there will *always* be more questions about such an event. The point of the Winter Bash is to create extra attention for the Stack Exchange sites during a holiday period (when traffic flags), so I'd say we should *celebrate* new questions on Meta about this.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but personally I downvote programming questions on Meta to get them off the front page, so others coming here by accident don't see them and assume they are in the right place to ask those.

Comment: As rule by [meta-tag:feature-request] ,simple if you agree cast upvote , or not cast downvote. :)

Comment: In response to your specific question about why people downvote programming questions asked on Meta, they do so for the same reason that wildly off topic questions are downvoted everywhere else on the network. The questions show a lack of any kind of research or consideration for the audience before asking, and many users do this explicitly to work around question bans on other sites. Downvotes also aid the automatic question ban algorithm, so that users are automatically blocked after they ask a few of these inappropriate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, My first question: Why some experienced users downvote such
>   questions?

Programming questions get downvoted on Meta because they meet the definition of what downvotes are for:

> **This question does not show any research effort; it is** unclear or **not useful.**

Had the user read any of the information that they were shown, before they asked question, they would have known that they were posting on the wrong site. Had they bothered to take a glance at the front page and read the question titles, they probably would have realized they were not looking at programming questions.

I'm not a new user anymore but when I click the "Ask Question" button, I'm still given an awful lot of indications that I'm not in the right place to ask programming questions:

[image]

**tl;dr**

We already do an awful lot of coaxing and hand-holding to try to steer new users in the right direction. Apart from providing personal guides there isn't much more we could do to make new users read the info plastered all over the site.