# Is there a "how to be a good community member" page?

Tags: discussion, community

In the webmasters meta page there has been a conversation about whether we should prompt people to accept correct answers.

There has been some comments about the way moderators etc deal with posts and answers and it prompted me to wonder if there is a page on how to be a good community member.  This would cover things like when and why to upvote, how to leave constructive comments, other activities to support the SE site.

Since I have to include a question: Is there a "how to be a good SE community member" page?  If not, should one be created?

Comment: Well, that *supposed* to be the [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics).

Comment: @ShadowWizard that has a lot of useful info, but a lot of noise.  Would be good to have it distilled somehow.

Comment: There is: The site's meta. "How to be an upstanding member of a large social group" is extremely broad and complex, full of subtleties, etiquette, common and not-so-common sense, policies, responsibility, consideration, etc., not to mention that community values change over time, and this is all complicated by the fact that any given member of these communities is both a follower *and* a leader (the members define the community). None of this can really be accurately distilled into a small, concrete guide beyond restating Wheaton's Law. Like any group: Learn by example and learn from mistakes.

Comment: And Help Center

Comment: @AnthonyPham the idea was a page within the help centre with quick access to the info.  The amount of info there now is approaching overwhelming and new users are unlikely to read it all if any

Comment: Well, if you follow the more important rules there like how to use your privileges, how to create good high-quality posts, that should be enough and is located in the Help Center

Comment: Steve, A lot of noise? In **[the Tour](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour)**? If you remove the screenshot visuals, the text compiles down to about a paragraph or two. It's hard to imagine distilling it down any further than that.

Comment: @Steve What sort of information that would help you "be a good community member" would you be looking for in the tour that you aren't seeing there at the moment?

Comment: @Steve I think, if I had to pick the help center topics that gave the most bang for the buck here, I'd go with [`/help/how-to-ask`](/help/how-to-ask) and [`/help/on-topic`](/help/on-topic). Every site's got those two pages, and I feel like if somebody reads and understands those, that covers like 99% of the problems a user may run into initially. In my experience, not following the guidelines laid out in those two pages seems to lead to the most bad initial experiences (comment battles, closures, downvotes, general *"thanks for not taking the time to read the help center"* vitriol, etc.).

Comment: @Steve I'm afraid it is not possible to have what you want. In order to learn how to be a "good community member" one has to read lots of stuff. No shortcuts.